# ASP.NET Web application - Web form - HTML issue

Tags: html, asp.net

I am using VS 2015 and created a web app. I have a default page and a Site.Master.

The input fields are defined inside a table and the Save button and message field is outside the table.

The save button is to the right of the table.

Why won't the Save button, message field and footer show below the table?

[image]

The Default page:

```html
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="OUTParameterWithSp._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
     <h1>OUT  Parameter with Stored Procedure</h1>

    <div> 
         <table align="left">  
                <tr>  
                    <td>  
                           UserName:  
                    </td>  
                    <td>  
                           <asp:TextBox ID="UserNameTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr>  
                    <td>  
                           Password:  
                    </td>  
                    <td>  
                          <asp:TextBox ID="PasswordTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr>  
                    <td>  
                           Confirm Password: 
                    </td>  
                    <td>  
                           <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPasswordTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox> 
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr>  
                    <td>  
                           Email: 
                    </td>  
                    <td>  
                           <asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr>  
                    <td>  
                           Country: 
                    </td>  
                    <td>  
                           <asp:TextBox ID="CountryTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
          </table>  

          <asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server" Text="Save" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="SaveButton_Click" />

          <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMsg" style="color:Red; font-weight :bold" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </div>  
</asp:Content>
```

The Site.Master page.

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="OUTParameterWithSp.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head runat="server">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET OUT Parameter with Stored Procedure Application</title>

        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
            <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>

        <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
                <Scripts>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                </Scripts>
            </asp:ScriptManager>

            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>

                        <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Out Parameter With Stored Procedure</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container body-content">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <hr />

                <footer>
                    <p>&copy; Dan C. - <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - Out Parameter With Stored Procedure (using ASP.NET Web Forms, a panel control, OUT Parameter and Bootstrap)</p>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<table align="left">` The table is aligned to the left of the other HTML elements. If you need further help, please include the rendered HTML (right-click on the page, select View Source).

Comment: @Heretic Monkey That is the solution. How can I give you credit?

Comment: I've put my comment into an answer to make it easier :).

Answer (score 0):

Try to put an HTML line break `<br/>` right after the closing `</table>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your `<table>` element has the attribute `align` set to `left`.

To fix, simply remove `align="left"` from your `table` element.

Note that the `align` attribute was deprecated (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#Attributes) or [the  HTML 4.01 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2) for more information).